# Take screenshot of current foreground application

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm using this code to take a screenshot in iOS:

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

The code is run when my application is in the background.

The problem is that it always takes a screenshot of *my* application, and instead I would like it to take the current screen.

Is it possible? how?

-- EDIT --

**Actually it is possible**, (see this [appstore application](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-recorder-hd/id594415065?mt=8) for example). So the remaining question is how?

Comment: privacy? sandboxing? no

Comment: Did I provide a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Actually no. I found this application https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-recorder-hd/id594415065?mt=8 (in the appstore) that allows you to record your iphone's desktop. If recording what you're doing is possible, then taking a simple screenshot should be possible as well

Comment: Actually, the reviews of that app seem to, uh, indicate the opposite.

Comment: Looking through the app, I don't see anything that indicates that it performs that function - except for that title :p

Comment: I used it and it actually works just fine (there s a persistant red bar at the top of the screen while it s recording though).

Comment: http://youtu.be/O8uBhwyZXps

Comment: @Majid Looks like it's running on a jailbroken device.

Comment: jailbreaking a device is legal, so it's still a legit app :)

Answer (score 7):

### No.

There's a reason the code always takes a screenshot of *your* application: it's *your* application.

Imagine the privacy implications of a backgrounded app being able to take screenshots of the current screen:

I, the user, have just hit the home button while using *Bob's Malicious Money Stealer*, and have switched over to look at my email - which happens to be a bill from my bank, which happens to include my account number, ATM card number, and my PIN (it's not a very good bank).

Now, the malicious app I was just using decides now would be an opportune time to see what I'm up to. It takes a screenshot of my current screen, and uploads it to a server.

The next day, all my money is gone, and I sue Apple.

Comment: On my Windows 7 machine, I install an application that has a key logger. The next day all my money is gone. Should I sue Microsoft ? :)

Comment: @MajidL Except that all I the user know (I don't ever look at app titles) is that I looked at the email on my *Apple* device, and the next day all my money was gone. Some idiot chisels a 3-foot deep hole in the highway. I flip my car over because of it. Who do I sue? Idiot or Highway Department?

Comment: Depends, does the Idiot work for the highway department ? .. anyway, apple do check the applications before they accept them, I don't think they would let *Bob's Money Stealer* go to the appstore.. :)

Comment: anyway, i asked because I saw some applications that help you cheat on some games by taking a screenshot of the game and then giving you the answer.. after rechecking the description, actually the player needs to take the screenshot himself and then the application reads it from the phone camera.

Comment: @MajidL This is true. However, it would be *possible* to sneak an app with this function - imagine an app that would ask a server whether or not to steal money, and the server only says `yes` after the app is approved.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible due to [sandboxing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html) of apps.  Apps are not supposed to obtain the state of other third-party apps.

Comment: this application records the whole user activity https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-recorder-hd/id594415065?mt=8 , so it actually is possible

Comment: To my knowledge, that (scamming?) app only records from video feeds (i.e. cameras). It is still not accessing (recording) the states of other apps.

Comment: That's neat (waves at camera o/).  But this brings up two things : 1) It's either running from a hacked iOS (read jailbreak) which will run anything and everything;  or 2) it's using a private API which, if noticed, would be removed from the App Store.  Perhaps this private API will be publicly available in a future release of iOS (iOS 7 maybe?!) or maybe it won't.  Either way, ***currently***, apps on the iTunes App Store don't legitemately have this functionality.

Comment: who said anything about non-jailbroken device? ;)

Comment: It would have been clearer if it was mentionned from the get-go instead of having to lead us in a merry chase to eventually deduce it.  A waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

if by entering the back ground you are referring to when a user minimizes the app, then no it is impossible for the fact apple would not allow you to make an application that takes a picture of the user's device from out side your app

but i may be misunderstanding your question, if you post 2 screen shots of the before and after you transition from foreground to background so i can see where you want to take the screen shot of, i can give you a better response :D